# Making every a href on my site a different color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am doing this with just static **CSS** using something that looks like the code displayed below.

```
#main-content > article.mh-loop-item.clearfix.post-95.post.type-post.status-publish.format-standard.has-post-thumbnail.hentry.category-singles.tag-kxngg-jxnes-italy > div > header > h3 > a {
color: blue;
}
#main-content > article.mh-loop-item.clearfix.post-93.post.type-post.status-publish.format-standard.has-post-thumbnail.hentry.category-singles.tag-aquil-eddie-guerrero > div > header > h3 > a {
color: red;
}
```

And for each **post ID** it generates a different color for that songs title to appear as, how ever I'm trying to do something a bit more advanced with Javascript or something that when ever there's an a href with a certain class it generates a random color for that link to appear as.

Comment: Where is your HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's the thing, I'm literally doing it with just CSS right now and it's extremely messy... my CSS file looks like complete cancer because it generates around 15 colors for ID's starting in certain numbers..

Comment: Why do you wanna break usability like this? People use the color and looks of links to navigate. Having the color be random will not be helpful to users.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie the idea is mostly just for post titles.

Comment: Why so many classes ?

Comment: Because it's Wordpress, I guess.

Comment: @Placeholder — Do you expect us to write the Javascript for you? Ain't gonna happen...

Comment: @ChristianBonato I don't expect that at all, I'm asking you mostly how I can achieve my output without it clustering my `style.css` file..

Comment: @Placeholder You must have some HTML to go with that CSS. Where's that?

Comment: Fine, but I agree with junkfoodjunkie. Random colors for links is an aberration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be achieved by jquery as below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('body a').each(function(){
    var color = 'rgb(' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ')';
    $(this).css("color", color);
  });
  
  function randomNumber(){
    return Math.floor(256*Math.random());
  }
  
});
```

```html
<a href="javascrip:void(0)">First link</a>
<a href="javascrip:void(0)">Second link</a>
<a href="javascrip:void(0)">Third link</a>
<a href="javascrip:void(0)">Fourth link</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

something like this work, please give it a try:

```js
/*I just hard coded everything*/
var yourClass = "article",
  hs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.' + yourClass)),
  colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow', 'lime'];

hs.forEach(function(elm) {
  elm.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
})
```

```html
<a href="#"> normal </a>

<a class="article" href="#"> title1 </a>
<a class="article" href="#"> title2 </a>
<a class="article" href="#"> title3 </a>
<a class="article" href="#"> title4 </a>
```

Comment: Good answer, because this one is giving OP the option to predefine the colors

Answer (score 2):

Ok if you really want to do this (don't see why but I like it :-) ). Then I'll show you a way. I'm gonna use jquery for this but feel free to improvise.

Create or edit your javascript file. And follow along (I'm assuming that your post titles have class called postTitle)

```
$('.postTitle').each(function () {
    var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    $( this ).css("color", "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")");
})
```

Comment: This is very helpful thanks, messing around with it now.